# When reading "the writing on the wall" in the ISS, which way is up?

Tags: iss, attitude, astronaut-lifestyle

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13887/12102) to the question *Is there really no difference between up and down in ISS?* says:

> ISS does have a sort of 'up and down', deliberately created as part of the design. All the modules apparently have a consistent 'up' orientation in one direction. The majority of lights are in the 'ceiling' and are set up to shine 'downward'. Furthermore, all the writing on the walls is pointed in the same direction, so that it is 'right side up' in relation to the 'floor' and 'ceiling'.

But it doesn't say what directions those are.

**Question:** When reading "the writing on the wall" and other signage and posted messages inside the ISS, which way is up? Which direction do the lights generally come from? Direction meaning nadir, zenith, cross-track, port, stern, starboard, *but please not X, Y, Z* because after seeing @OrganicMarble's [artwork](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20364/12102) I'll never be able to get them straight.

Comment: You want to hear Earth facing as the reference, since that is easiest to visualize.

Comment: Why the hurtful omission of forward and aft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward is toward the US segment, +X in the ISS coordinate system.

Aft is toward the Russian segment, -X in the ISS coordinate system.

Starboard is toward the AMS, +Y in the ISS coordinate system.

Port is toward the Cupola, -Y in the ISS coordinate system.

Down or Deck is toward the Nadir, +Z in the ISS coordinate system.

Up or Overhead is toward the zenith side, -Z in the ISS coordinate system.

Comment: I thought the cupola was on the bottom of the station, ie in nadir direction?

Comment: It certainly started out on Node 3 nadir, but I haven't necessarily been keeping up with current events. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tranquility_(ISS_module). I think he means "towards the cupola when moving laterally away from the fore/aft axis", not "in the direction the top of the cupola is facing".

Comment: It is on N3N, but N3 is on the port side of the module stack.  The cupola was chosen as the unique piece of hardware that is on the port side but not the starboard side of the XZ plane.

Comment: JEM, is further port, but also further forward, and BEAM is roughly the same place as the cupola, but points aft

Comment: @uhoh Things are oriented internally precisely as I stated.  The Cupola is an exception, as it's generally treated as facing "up".

Comment: @JCRM That may be, but quibbling over which is more port is an exercise in navel-gazing.

Comment: indeed, I was trying to illustrate there were no "good" choices for indicating port